# Is there a way to keep quick documentation always on in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there a way to keep the quick documentation always on or pinned to tip's window in Intellij rather than pressing F1 everytime?

I see this.

[image]

But would like to see this without pressing F1.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Configure it to **Open as a Tool Window**:

[image]

and have it always opened on the side:

[image]